# Javscript Jest test framework: when is a mock unmocked?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jestjs

I want to mock a module and a function for a specific test. I have the following:

```
test("my test", () => {
   jest.mock("some_module")
   some_module.some_function = jest.fn();
   ...

})

test("another test", () => {
    ...
});
```

My question is, when the test is finished, will both mocks be "unset" so that I can use the real implementation for my next test? Or do I have to explicitly remove all mocks myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when the test is finished will all of the mocks be "unset"?

Jest tests are sandboxed on a test-file basis, so ordinarily after all tests in that file have been run, all the mocks would be restored.

However, what you are doing there: `some_module.some_function = jest.fn();` is not mocking via Jest's mocking mechanism, it is monkey-patching an imported function.  This will not be removed by Jest.

You should be doing something like this instead:

```
import { some_function } from 'some-module-path';

jest.mock('some-module-path');

test('my test', () => {
  ...
  expect(some_function).toHaveBeenCalled(); // e.g.
}
```

UPDATE:

After the discussion in comments, here is an example of doing a simple monkey-patch safely in Jest, so that it is restored for subsequent tests in the same file:

```
// foo.js -----------------------------------
export const foo = () => 'real foo';


// bar.js -----------------------------------
import { foo } from './foo';

export const bar = () => foo();


// bar.test.js ------------------------------
import { bar } from './bar';
import * as fooModule from './foo';

describe('with mocked foo', () => {
  let originalFoo;

  beforeAll(() => {
    // patch it!
    originalFoo = fooModule.foo;
    fooModule.foo = () => 'mocked foo';
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    // put it back again!
    fooModule.foo = originalFoo;
  });

  test('mocked return value from foo()', () => {
    expect(bar()).toEqual('mocked foo');
  });
});

describe('with real foo', () => {
  test('expect real return value from foo()', () => {
    expect(bar()).toEqual('real foo');
  });
});
```

UPDATE 2:

Another alternative, you can mock the dependency and use the original implementation temporarily with `jest.requireActual`:

```
import { bar } from './bar';
import { foo } from './foo';

jest.mock('./foo');
foo.mockReturnValue('mocked foo');
const fooModule = jest.requireActual('./foo')

test('mocked return value from foo()', () => {
  expect(bar()).toEqual('mocked foo');
});

test('real return value from foo()', () => {
  foo.mockImplementation(fooModule.foo);
  expect(bar()).toEqual('real foo');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So, in the next test the mocks would have been unset, correect? I'm a little confused with your wording of "test-file basis". It seems to imply that the mocks would be unset only after ALL the tests in the test file have finished

Comment: Hi nz_21, updated my answer to be a little clearer I hope; yes they are only removed by jest after ALL tests are done within that file, but you are overwriting a function reference on the imported module - jest is not aware or in control of that.

Comment: Also to add, if you are for instance checking that the mock has been called in several tests, then you might want to use `beforeEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());` so that the information the mocks store about calls made to them and arguments etc. are cleared before every test.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why it's better to call `jest.mock()` globally rather than within the test function

Comment: For my use-case, I want to mock a module and a function for a specific test (as shown in the code in the Q). I have edited the Q to make it clear

Comment: @nz_21 use `sinon` instead.  it has a feature 'createSandbox' that can control lifetime of mocks.   or use the jest `resetModules` feature, which basically reloads everything from scratch.

Comment: @nz_21 See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks - "Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs jest.mock('moduleName') to be in the same scope as the require/import statement."  In my experience, `jest.mock()` inside tests doesn't work well.

Comment: @RobinBalmforth ok, thanks. I am specifically concerned if my monkey-patched function will live on for the other tests too

Comment: this seems incredibly complicated and fragile :(

Comment: @nz_21 The short answer is: it will live on, it won’t be removed.  But typically you would mock the modules you wanted to mock for the whole file and only clear the calls and/or switch the mock implementation between tests.  Your use case is unusual.

Comment: Is it really? I basically just want my mocked deps to be isolated within their own test...it sounds like a reasonable thing to want :)

Comment: Not unreasonable, just not much of an issue usually :) When unit testing you would usually want to isolate by mocking dependencies. If you don't then it's really an integration test and you wouldn't normally mix these. Technically, the reason is that jest applies mocks via module loader so if one test has already run without mocks it's too late to apply a mock - the unit has already imported everything. In some cases a simple function patch works, that's how sinon applies stubs, but the jest way is more powerful and can mock where sinon/patching can't (ES6 default exports for example).

Comment: @nz_21 I've updated my answer with a couple of examples, hope that helps :)